# The select statement only works on first record, it doesnt retrieve any information from the other records

Tags: mysql, jdbc

```
    public String searchSinger(String singer) throws SQLException
    {
     PreparedStatement ps = null;;
     ResultSet rs = null;
     String query = "SELECT id FROM ng_singers WHERE name = ?";
     try{
         ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
         ps.setString(1, singer);

         rs = ps.executeQuery();
         if(rs.next())
         {   
             String id = rs.getString(1); 
             display = display + "\t" + id;              
         } 
         System.out.println(display);
         return display;
         }
         catch(Exception e){
         return display;
        }
        finally{
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
        }

        }
```

so this code works if I enter the name in the first record, but does not work for all record. I have table ng_singers in the db with records id:1 name: michael, id:2 name:janet, and so on. total 9 rows in the table. So the query only works for the name michael and 3 other names in row 5,7 and 9. the query does not retrieve data for rows 2,3,4,6 and 8. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if i understand your question correctly.

If you want to retrieve all the records you have to do a

```
while(rs.Next()){
}
```

That iterates over all records and automatically assigns the next value to rs.

If you want to retrieve your commented fields, you have to add them to your "SELECT dob" like "SELECT dob,name,sex,record FROM" ..etc

Comment: I have edited the question so it is more clear. the query only works for certain records and not all records.

Comment: @user2900638 The problem remains the same. You are using `if (rs.next())` where you should be using `while (rs.next())`.